# How listen timer tick globally?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I want to have a single main timer in my wpf c# app, that´s counting/running independent of current shown page. 
My software create different custom controls at truntime, and inside of that controls I need the ability of listen the main tick.

```
  namespace window6
  {
  public partial class Window6 : Window
  {.......
```

I already try this:

```
  public static DispatcherTimer GlobalTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
  GlobalTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
  GlobalTimer.IsEnabled = true;
```

Then on any custom control I fire a timer event:

```
  window6.Window6.GlobalTimer.Tick +=  (global_Elapsed);
```

The problem is this code act like a new timer on every custom control I use, so every timer event is fired inside every custom control,  run as a new timer running not in sync. Not act as a single timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't be referencing the same timer, somehow.
I created a static class:

```html
using System.Timers;

namespace wpf_GlobalTimer
{
    public static class TimerParent
    {
        public static Timer GlobalTimer { get; set; } = new Timer(3000)
        {
            AutoReset = true,
            Enabled = true
        };
    }
}
```

I then added a simple window with animation:

```html
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="TestStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation 
                From="200"
                To="0" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Height)" 
                Storyboard.TargetName="Rect"
                FillBehavior="Stop" 
                Duration="0:0:2"
                />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Name="Rect" Height="200" Fill="Green"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and

```html
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private Timer timer = null;
        private Storyboard sb = null;
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer = TimerParent.GlobalTimer;
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

            sb = this.Resources["TestStoryboard"] as Storyboard;
        }
        private  void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() =>
            {
                sb.Begin();
            }));
        }
    }
```

in Mainwindow I added a button to instantiate and show multiple window1

```html
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window win = new Window1();
            win.Show();
        }
```

When I spin that up and click the button several times I have 3 instances of window1 and their animations are in sync.

Comment: Thanks so much !!!!
I love when person like you take the time to explain with a very super clear with a  working example!!!
Thanks thanks thanks!!

Comment: Note that i had limited time to do this so it's a bit quick n dirty. Dispatchertimer fires on the ui thread and you could maybe avoid that invokeasync stuff with that.